# Word for thing whose parts are independently movable?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm thinking of a specific word here for something that is broken up into pieces which are connected by a kind of joint that allows each piece free motion -- like a Rubik's cube. I believe the word may have something like "sect" as part of it, but I could easily be wrong.

Comment: "Sectional", like a sofa?

Answer (score 3):

I think I figured it out. I think I was merging three related words in my mind:

- articulated, as in an articulated joint
- segmented
- sectional, as Elliott pointed out